# Using the HttpClient from WebApplicationFactory in .NET 6.0 always returns 'Not found' on calling the SendAsync method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpclient, .net-6.0, webapi

We're having an .NET 6.0 WebAPI and are building unittests for it. But somehow the SendAsync method in the UnitTest always returns 'Not found'.
Here's the relevant code:

```
      [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestActiviteitCRUD()
        {
            WebApplicationFactory<Program> applicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            var client = applicationFactory.CreateClient();
// Activiteit toevoegen
            var testActiviteit = new ActiviteitInsertMetConflicten
            {
                conflicten = new List<Conflict>(),
                activiteitInsert = new ActiviteitInsert
                {
                    Startdatumtijd = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    Einddatumtijd = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(60),
                    ActiviteittypeId = 9,
                    SpecialistId = 1,
                    SpecialismeId = 1,
                    StandaardtijdblokId = null,
                    ExtraTijd = false,
                    IsHeleDag = false,
                    AandachtsgebiedId = 1,
                    PLANstatusId = 0,
                    HeeftPlanningsConflict = false
                }
            };
            var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/Activiteit", testActiviteit);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

PostAsJsonAsync works fine (and PutAsJsonAsync also), but further on:

```
var actdel = new ActiviteitDeleteMetVraagEnAntwoord();
            actdel.activiteitId = id;
            List<VraagEnAntwoord> vragenEnAntwoorden = new List<VraagEnAntwoord>();
            actdel.vragenEnAntwoorden = vragenEnAntwoorden;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Delete;
            request.RequestUri = client.BaseAddress;            
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(actdel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

The last line (response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();) always returns a 'not found'. And while debugging the UnitTest we can see that the routine to Delete the object is indeed not hit.

But it works fine when we delete an object in another application which calls the same delete-routine in the same web api. In that other application we don't use WebApplicationFactory.
When we use Swagger to test the WebApi it works fine also.
So only in the UnitTest using WebApplicationFactory, we cannot use the SendAsync. What's wrong?
(We cannot use the DeleteAsync method since we need to send a whole object)

Comment: wild guess, but maybe request.RequestUri = client.BaseAddress; should be request.RequestUri = client.BaseAddress+ "/Activiteit";

Comment: So the unit test should issue a real delete reqest?

Comment: Thank you RdPC! It was just a matter of adding 'Activiteit' (sometimes we look in the wrong direction :))

Comment: Thank you Magnus. Yes, it is allowed to issue a real delete request. I know that this delete can also be 'mocked up', so that it just pretends to delete an object. But in our case we're always connected to a test environment. And in this particular unit test first an object is added and in the same unittest the same object is also deleted